# WSO2 API Manager 3.2 disable the access-token

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

How in WSO2 API Manager 3.2 disable the access-token mechanism?
I want to access my API directly, no authorization, no access tokens. How can I turn them off? Alas, I didn’t find any information other than this: x-auth-type: No, but I didn’t find in which file to change it.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the Security for each API Resource from the Publisher Portal. Open the API that you don't want security-enabled and navigate to the Resources tab. Expand the resources, and turn off the Security.

This will disable the security for that particular API Resource, and you will be able to invoke the respective Resource without any Access Tokens. You can learn more about the configurations and steps in this [Doc: Under Point 7 > b > iii](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/design-api/create-api/create-a-rest-api/)